# Docker-for-selenium on Windows

Tags: docker, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, zalenium, selenium-docker

Currently selenium HQ/docker-for-selenium is available for Linux os.

Here they are trying to implement selenium grid using docker, on Linux.

My  main aim is achieving the same in windows. I am unaware what challenges I will  face here.

So creating this thread to discuss the challenge while implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For windows to support the IE in docker we need to understand two things.

1)**Windows do not provide GUI capability inside the docker containers like  XVBF in Linux.**

**2) No headless IE**

Feel Free to explore this project in order to understand how they are enabling GUI in Linux containers.

Link to the project: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

***UPDATES***:

Still there is no official approach to run IE/EDGE inside docker as
**"[No Windows docker images have GUI, so we cannot test IE11, EDGE.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/214)"**

But,We can install virtual-box and make this happen.

***This approach adds extra layer of virtualization[Nesting of virtualization] on the top of docker to make the IE/Edge execution happen and I think in near future it may leads to to performance issue for heavy testing.***

If Selenium testing is what you are looking for and don't have heavy load , you can give a try to the approach mentioned in the link.

[Youtube - Selenium Windows containers in Docker under Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJCvvfSE2FE)

[Github - Windows Images](https://github.com/aerokube/windows-images)

[Blogpost - selenium-on-windows-docker-revolution](https://medium.com/@aandryashin/selenium-on-windows-docker-revolution-f5a7eab205ad)